# Adding an index to a model's row

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I use the rails_best_practises gem and it came back to me with this alert:

```
/../db/schema.rb:65 - always add db index (comments => [user_id])
```

So in db/schema.rb, the line 65 shows the schema of the comments table.

```
 create_table "comments", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "commenter"
    t.text     "body"
    t.integer  "post_id"
    t.string   "email"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

So what it asks for is to add an index (something) like the one below?

`add_index "comments", ["user_id"], name: "index_comments_on_user_id", using: :btree`

If so, when I create a new rails migration to accomplish this, will the migration be like that?

```
def change
  add_index :comments, :user_id
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the **[Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html)**

> If you'd like to add an index on the new column, you can do that as
>   well

So,You should do this to generate a migration file of adding an index.

```
rails generate migration AddIndexToComments user_id:integer:index
```

This will produce a migration file like this

```
class AddIndexToComments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_index :comments, :user_id
  end
end
```